# Why Microsoft Edge opens CSV instead of showing save dialog?

Tags: csv, attachment, microsoft-edge, content-disposition

Here's the [example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ooom74wi).

In all browsers except Microsoft Edge when user clicks on link then he prompted to save CSV file. Microsoft Edge, unexpected for me, opens it in browser like normal text.

CSV file in example above have these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-disposition: attachment
```

Any idea how to force Microsoft Edge to show save dialog instead of opening CSV as plain text.

Comment: FWIW, the content-type is incorrect. But I don't believe that matters here.

Comment: @JulianReschke thanks for that advise. I changed Content-Type to `text/csv` and updated the question. But, as you assumed it does not fixed the issue from question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried here : https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/

there is this link to a CSV : http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv

It is downloading on Microsoft Edge on my side (not showing it).

The header they use is this one :

```
Content-Type: application/x-csv
```

Can you try this ?

Comment: You're totally right! With this non-standard mime type Edge started to behave like it should with CSV files. Thank you and welcome to SO!